# Folder View in a viewtree with MVVM structure?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have three files in a project called data that is a datalibrary in visual studio I have watched a tutorial called MVVM tutorial c# together with a filetree! this is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2ZvZwDZmJU at about 12:19 he writes this row of code

```
return GetLogicalDrives().Select(drive => new DirectoryItem { fullPath = drive, Type = DirectoryItemType.Drive }).ToList();
```

This code does not work for me and I know that I have no `Directory.GetLogicalDrives` but that is not how my folder view looks like so my namespace for the three different files that he that far in the video is using is Data and this is my code from these three Files...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Data
{
    public static  class DirectoryStructure
    {
        public static List<DirectoryItem> GetLogicalDrives()
        {
           return GetLogicalDrives().Select(drive => new DirectoryItem { fullPath = drive, Type = DirectoryItemType.Drive }).ToList(); 
        }

        public static string GetFilefolderName(string path)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                return string.Empty;    
            }

            var normalizedPath = path.Replace('/', '\\');    
            var lastIndex = normalizedPath.LastIndexOf('\\');

            if(lastIndex <= 0)
            {
                return path; 
            }

            return path.Substring(lastIndex + 1);   
        }
    }

    public class DirectoryItem
    {
        public DirectoryItemType Type { get; set;}
        public string fullPath { get; set; }
        public string Name { get { return DirectoryStructure.GetFilefolderName(this.fullPath); } }  
    }

    public enum DirectoryItemType
    {
        Drive,
        File, 
        Folder
    }
}
```

I have no clue why I am getting an error from that row? My folder structure looks like this project: Data \Directory in this folder I have DirectoryStructure and the rest of the files I have beneath the same file path but one more folder called `DataFolder`. Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work for me?

Comment: Try Environment.GetLogicalDrives()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code :

1. Your `GetLogicalDrives` method calls itself in its body, it will not be able to work  with your logic, because there is no List to browse.
2. An `using` directive is missing in your file. To acces to `Directory` class and then call the `GetLogicalDrivers` method you must add `using System.IO` at the top of your file.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I was thinking that i was calling it in itself but if you look at the video at exact the time code i gave you he does exactly that?

Comment: In the video it's not called herself but delegates a call to a method with the same name but from the Directory class. I think you shouldn't have seen it correctly, he does this :

`return Directory.GetLogicalDrives().Select(drive => new DirectoryItem { fullPath = drive, Type = DirectoryItemType.Drive }).ToList();`

Comment: yea he references the directory but that file i have not seen him create at any point

Comment: or well i mean that class i have not seen him create at any point

Comment: no now i understand what you were saying i didnt get that you meant that it was a part of the system.io library